Qt Не обновляет интерфейс после пересборки
собираю qt проект - начальная конфигурация сборка и запуск прошли успешно - программа запускается. Но при изменениях в ui (в Widget editor) - изменения видны в редакторе но их нет при перезапуске.
Clean, rebuild из меню проекта - все испробовано.
Подскажите в чем может быть дело
UPD: один раз получилось что обновился интерфейс - изменилось слово на кнопке - но воспроизвести не получается, опять все изменения после запуска не видны. При этом например удаляю кнопку- при сборке ругается что на кнопку осталась ссылка, удаляю - ссылку, пересобираю - теперь собирается корректно но кнопка на месте (хотя в редакторе нет и в коде ссылка удалена)
UPD2: перезапуск QT помогает, но перезапускать после каждых изменений - странно

Инструменты -> Параметры -> Сборка и Запуск У вас стоит галочка "Сохранять все файлы перед сборкой"?

@needKVAS спасибо, галочка стояла но в процессе поиска меню дошло что не так - закрытие окна приложения не останавливало приложение (оставалось в трее), соответственно при перезапуске использовалось уже запущенное.
Полностью завершить приложение перед пересборкой решает вопрос.
